# How to tell SQL to return TRUE on "positive value occurance" rather than using SUM(field) >0 condition

Tags: sql, select, db2, query-optimization

I am doing aggregation on QTY field which will have either 0 or positive value. So presence of any positive number can predict sum will be greater than 0. Is there any way to return true once a positive value found rather than doing summation of all rows ? It is DB2 database.

```
 select *
    from a
    where a_id in (1,2,3,4)
    and
    (
      flag = 'Y' 
      or 
      (select sum(qty) from b where b.a_id = a.a_id) > 0
    )
```

Comment: your supposed logic would fail if there exist negative values in the column.

Comment: True, but the aggregate function has to add 500+ rows if data exist and that made me curious to find a way to return TRUE on any positive value occurrence rather than doing addition of 500 field values. I may be wrong with my idea though ..

Comment: `sum` is fast enough. and adding up 500 + row values isn't as tedious as you think

Comment: Nice then, I am using sum only and it pretty quick like you said. Wanted to cross check with you guys if any way exists. It would be better if SQL add aggregate function like hasAnyPositiveValue() , hasAnyNegativeValue() .. Just saying ..

Comment: and that is what exactly the answer below does. look up how `exists` works

Comment: Alright, I will search for some DB2 Exists docs and read it then. Thanks for explaining :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91116/discussion-between-raja-and-vkp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it any faster with EXISTS?

```
 select *
    from a
    where a_id in (1,2,3,4)
    and
    (
      flag = 'Y' 
      or 
      EXISTS (select b.a_id from b where b.a_id = a.a_id and qty>0)
    )
```

Comment: I have to check but the particular aggregation has to sum 500+ rows if data exist. 90% of the time there will be data..Exists can improve but I am wondering if any other function or trick is there to return TRUE on any positive value occurrence

Comment: I think you'll find that EXISTS does exactly that. Good luck, Raja.

Comment: Oops !! My mistake only :| I should have noticed that qty>0 and exists  ... Thanks for keeping patience through out my nonsense :)